# Read content of a file and display the result

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, search, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

**My scenario:**

I am using SharePoint 2019, I am using the code below to search for a particular word in all the files found on the site.

Once the files with the word that is queried is found, I want to display the paragraph where that word is found. stream is not being accepted in  the function WordprocessingDocument.Open. Error:  cannot convert from 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult'

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint2019/sites/test/"))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> stream = null;
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";
            keywordQuery.EnablePhonetic = true;
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);                
            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2})", resultRow["Title"], resultRow["Path"], resultRow["Write"]);

                File file= clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(resultRow["Path"].ToString());
                stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);
                Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
```

Comment: What is the problem/question? What have you tried? What worked? What failed?

Comment: @Nils Question updated with updated code.

Comment: I have currently no way to test, but have you tried to move the `stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();` three lines down? (I.e. after `clientContext.ExecuteQuery();` ?)

Comment: @Nils Yes the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `Value` of your `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<System.IO.Stream>`. See [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee539241%28v%3Doffice.15%29) for reference.

So.. Change:

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);
```

to

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream.Value, true);
```

Comment: Now am getting error: the stream was not opened for writing

Comment: I changed editable=true to false and it worked
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream.Value,false);

Comment: the stream is non-writeable. If your Word-library need the stream writeable I'd suggest copying it to a memory-Stream

Comment: glad I could help